# Maintaining state between Angular2 modules

Tags: angular, typescript, module, singleton

I have an app with multiple modules created using Angular2 RC-5.  Each module is a stand on its own entity with it's own landing component/page but I should be able to switch between these modules without losing state.  All the modules use lazy loading and I can currently browse to all my modules as expected.

The problem arises as I have added a textbox as an example on each landing page and if I enter a value in the textbox then return back to home/main and go back to the module to view the textbox, it's now empty.  The module is new every time.  Is there a way to make modules effectively like singletons for the lifetime of the app or is this not possible?

Thanks in advance,
Stephen

Comment: How about using a shared service in both the module and using the same field to hold the textbox data.?

Comment: The textbox is only an example, I need to maintain a lot of state :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create an object to hold the properties you wish to track, update that object as your fields change and either store in local storage or use a service...

Comment: Yeah, the main component and sub-components will hold the objects I wish to track but it gets re-created along with the module.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but when your objects get recreated, you pull from local storage and update the objects in the new module. Local storage shouldn't be wiped out as long as your session is good.

Comment: You need to hold the properties in global service, not in the component. Component will be created and destroyed depending on view. A global service will hold the same data.

Comment: In a scenario where you have a large app with multiple function areas I don't think it makes sense to try to track the data in a single, global location... that would be quite messy after a while.